# Special calculation issue

Tags: javascript, math, calculation

I'd have to functions "to()" and "from()" where I'd like to calculate using `to(n) -> x` a number `n` to another number and back again `from(x) -> n`.

This are the two functions:

```
function to(number) {
  return (4 * number) - 26
}    
function from(number) {
  return (number / 4 ) - 26
}
```

But obviously this is not working as expected: The `from` does not seems to work. Can somebody help me I'm clueless af. Is it even possible to calculate the number back again?

```js
function to(number) {
  return (4 * number) - 26
}

function from(number) {
  return (number / 4 ) - 26
}


let a = to(30)
console.log(a)

let b = from(a)
console.log(b) // should get "30"
```

Comment: This can be solved with algebra, which you should learn if you're going to be programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```js
function to(number) {
  return (4 * number) - 26
}

function from(number) {
  return (number + 26 ) / 4
}


let a = to(30)
console.log(a)

let b = from(a)
console.log(b) // should get "30"
```

```
   to = 4 * from - 26
=> to + 26 = 4 * from
=> (to + 26) / 4 = from
=> from = (to + 26) / 4
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrived at that solution? There is no value to the asker in this answer just providing the correct inverse function.

Comment: at the end is mathematical derivation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your functions are not reversable because of that -26... you need to add that 26 to second number before dividing, to get a proper result...

```
function from(number) {
  return (number + 26) / 4
}
```

Those are symmetrical, yours are not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 30 then your formula should be like this.

```
function from(number){
 return (number+26)/4;
}
```